# Google Chrome DevTools save rendered fonts to disk

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Screen]

Is it possible to save rendered fonts from Chrome DevTools ?

I've been trying to find them in network section, but it seems that font files are encrypted or stored in unknown format